# Jquery issue with $.when

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a call back function which will check for 60secs. If file avaible then will return true else will return false. The call back function I'm calling after ajax call.. Here is code below :

```
$.ajax({
    type: '..',
    url: '..',
    data: '..',
    success: function(data) {
        window.loadFile(data);
    }
})

window.loadFile = function(filePath) { // I'm getting the data. Now passing to call back function
    $.when(window.waitTillFileExistsAndLoad(filePath)).done(function(data) {
        alert(data) // here data is giving me undefined.. 
    });
}

var timer = 0;
window.waitTillFileExistsAndLoad = function(fileName) {

    var checkFile;

    return $.get(fileName, function(data) { // If file found.. 

        timer = 0;
        return true;

    }).error(function() { // If file not found.. 

        timer += 1; 

        if(timer == 30) {

            timer = 0;
            clearTimeout(checkFile);
            return false;

        } else {

            console.log('error occured');
            checkFile = setTimeout(function() {
                window.waitTillFileExistsAndLoad(fileName);
            }, 2000);

        }

    });
}
```

The issue is that when I'm using `$.when()` it's giving me undefined. Please suggest me what's wrong in my code.

Comment: You're recalling your method but forgetting to `return` the result - hence it's `undefined` (no return value)

Comment: Jamiec, I'm returning the result as true or false in waitTillFileExistsAndLoad () method.. is it anything wrong in that ?

Comment: Never use `done`/`fail`/`error` for callbacks that `return` something - they don't chain. Always use `then` and `catch`.

Comment: But note that `catch` wasn't added to jQuery api until version 3. What version of jQuery is being used?

Comment: @B77 - the one inside your `setTimeout` does not (and, can not due to it being inside a callback itself) return the result.